# Read port number from user

Tags: c, input

I state that I am a beginner with C.
I'm writing a server in C, my code is as follows:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 { 
     ds_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
     if(ds_socket == -1)
         errore_exit("creation socket");

     struct sockaddr_in server;
     struct sockaddr client; 

     //set sockadrr_in

     server.sin_family = AF_INET;
     server.sin_port = htons(9999); 
     server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

     //binding    
     if(bind(ds_socket, &server,sizeof(server)) == -1)
         errore_exit("binding");

   if(listen(ds_socket,1000) == -1)
       errore_exit("listen");

   client_socket = accept(ds_socket,&client,&(sizeof(client))); 

   if(client_socket == -1)
       errore_exit("accept");    
}
```

In setting the structure server, I spent a number of any port (9999), but I would like to implement it in this way: server ask the port number to the user before assigning an address to the socket using the bind. The user enters the number of port Keyboard and the server saves within a variable "port" which is then passed into the setting of the structure.

I can not do that last part just described: someone could help me?

Comment: What are the difficulties?  RTFM for [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: How to read input from a user should have come very early in just about any book or tutorial. Haven't you done that before?

Comment: Smell like homeworks....

Comment: Your real question is not related to networking, therefore I removed such tags. I also changed the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanf` to read user input

```
int var;
scanf("%d", &var);
```

Now `var` contains an integer that the user typed in.

You'll notice that the format specifier is very similar to `printf`(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

scanf returns the amount of values it read successfully. So to make sure user enters a number, check that scanf returns 1.

A problem with scanf, is that it leaves a trailing newline in `stdin`. So, you'll need to flush it:

```
void flush()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        ;
}
```

This consumes all the characters until a newline is seen. Dont use `fflush(stdin)` to flush though.

Read about scanf in K&R (page 128, section 7.4): http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf

A full scanf example:

```
int main()
{
    int age;
    printf("What is your age?");

    if (scanf("%d", &age) > 0)
        printf("You are %d yrs old", age);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Numbers only!");
    flush();                      /* use the flush function shown above*/

    return 0;
}
```